# Basic ExtJS 5 example gives error

Tags: extjs

I am trying to run the basic example of ExtJS 5 provided [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/getting_started/welcome_to_extjs.html).
When try running it I get in Firebug: 403 Forbidden error.
I guess this is related with loading the library:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/trial/5.0.0/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/trial/5.0.0/build/ext-all.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/trial/5.0.0/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
```

Any idea what is causing these errors and how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Apparently the trail CDN URLs are throwing 403 error. Change them to `...ext/gpl/5.0.0/..` Here is [an URL](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286738-Latest-extjs-5.0-gpl-cdn) you can checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the ExtJS (version 5.1.0) library, placed it in the same folder with my index.html file and I included the library using these links:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-5.1.0/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-5.1.0/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-5.1.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Which for some reason makes it considerably slow to load my index.html but at least it works.